# wxhaskell asynchronous updates

Tags: haskell, wxhaskell

I am using WxHaskell to graphically show the state of a program that advertises state updates using TCP (which I decode using Data.Binary).  When an update is received, I want to update the display.  So I want the GUI to update its display asynchronously. I know that `processExecAsync` runs a command line process asynchronously, but I don't think this is what I want.

Comment: Can you clarify your question. What exactly are you seeking? A model for notifying a Haskell process from a separate process?

Comment: Here is an example.  In a separate process, there is a counter.  Every time that the counter is incremented, it sends a message via TCP to other Haskell processes (the clients).  The clients manage a gui (in WxHaskell) that displays the value of the counter.  When an update is received by the client, I want to update the counter on the display.

Comment: Based on your comment I have posted an answer.  What concepts, if any, in my answer relate to your question?  Haskell threads (forkIO)?  Communication between threads (MVars, STM/TVars)?  Something else or not in my answer?

Answer (score 2):

This is rough code using transactional variables (i.e. software transactional memory).  You could use an IORef, MVar, or numerous other constructs.

```
main = do
    recvFunc <- initNetwork
    cntTV <- newTVarIO 0
    forkIO $ threadA recvFunc cntTV
    runGUI cntTV 0
```

Above you start the program, initialize the network and a shared variable `cntTV`

```
threadA recvCntFromNetwork cntTVar = forever $ do
    cnt <- recvCntFromNetwork
    atomically (writeTVar cntTVar cnt)
```

`threadA` receives data from the network and writes the new value of the counter to the shared variable.

```
runGUI cntTVar currentCnt = do
    counter <- initGUI
    cnt <- atomically $ do
        cnt <- readTVar cntTVar
        if (cnt == currentCnt)
            then retry
            else return cnt
    updateGUICounter counter cnt
    runGUI cntTVar cnt
```

`runGUI` reads the shared variable and if there is a change will update the GUI counter.  FYI, the runGUI thread won't wake up on `retry` until `cntTVar` is modified, so this isn't a CPU hogging polling loop.

In this code I've assumed you have functions named `updateGUICounter`, `initGUI`, and `initNetwork`.  I advise you use Hoogle to find the location of any other functions you don't already know and learn a little about each module.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  This is sort of what I had in mind.  Unfortunately, we need to call the wxHaskell function `start` which starts the event loop.  If we run `start runGUI` then the event loop will never be started.  And if we `forkIO` the STM stuff then the GUI is not updated (at least when I tried).

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with a kind of hack that seems to work.  Namely, use an event timer to check an update queue:

```
startClient :: IO (TVar [Update])
startClient = /*Connect to server, 
                listen for updates and add to queue*/

gui :: TVar [Update] -> IO ()
gui trdl = do
  f <- frame [text := "counter", visible := False]
  p <- panel f []
  st <- staticText p []
  t <- timer f [interval := 10, on command := updateGui st]
  set f [layout := container p $ fill $ widget st, clientSize := (sz 200 100), visible := True]
 where
   updateGui st = do
             rdl <- atomically $ readTVar trdl
             atomically $ writeTVar trdl []
             case rdl of
               [] -> return ()
               dat : dl -> set st [text := (show dat)]

main :: IO ()
main = startClient >>= start gui
```

So a client listens for the updates on the TCP connection, adds them to a queue.  Every 10ms, an event is raised whose action is to check this queue and show the latest update in a static text widget.

If you have a better solution, please let me know!

Comment: From what I can tell there isn't any reason gui can't retry on the TVar and do this async (but yes, wx breaks seemingly any time the thread blocks).  I also tried inverting the concept and writing `\str -> set st [text := str]` into the TVar then having `startClient` call this to update the GUI, but that seems to block indefinitely on `set`.  WX has proven rather frustrating so I think I'll stick with GTK as a result.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution without a busy wait at:
   http://snipplr.com/view/17538/

However you might choose a higher eventId in order to avoid conflicts with existing ids.

Here is some code from my module http://code.haskell.org/alsa/gui/src/Common.hs:

```
myEventId :: Int
myEventId = WXCore.wxID_HIGHEST+100
    -- the custom event ID, avoid clash with Graphics.UI.WXCore.Types.varTopId

-- | the custom event is registered as a menu event
createMyEvent :: IO (WXCore.CommandEvent ())
createMyEvent =
   WXCore.commandEventCreate WXCore.wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED myEventId

registerMyEvent :: WXCore.EvtHandler a -> IO () -> IO ()
registerMyEvent win io =
   WXCore.evtHandlerOnMenuCommand win myEventId io


reactOnEvent, reactOnEventTimer ::
   SndSeq.AllowInput mode =>
   Int -> WX.Window a -> Sequencer mode ->
   (Event.T -> IO ()) ->
   IO ()
reactOnEvent _interval frame (Sequencer h _) action = do
   mvar <- MVar.newEmptyMVar

   void $ forkIO $ forever $ do
      MVar.putMVar mvar =<< Event.input h
      WXCore.evtHandlerAddPendingEvent frame =<< createMyEvent

   registerMyEvent frame $
      MVar.takeMVar mvar >>= action

-- naive implementation using a timer, requires Non-Blocking sequencer mode
reactOnEventTimer interval frame sequ action =
   void $
   WX.timer frame [
      WX.interval := interval,
      on command  := getWaitingEvents sequ >>= mapM_ action]
```

The code shows two ways to handle the problem:

- `reactOnEventTimer` does a busy wait using the WX timer.
- `reactOnEvent` only gets active when an event actually arrives. This is the prefered solution.

In my example I wait for ALSA MIDI sequencer messages. The Event.input call waits for the next ALSA message to come. The `action` gets the results of Event.input, that is, the incoming ALSA messages, but it is run in the WX thread.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Whilst this may answer the 
question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.